Motor Direction standard nomenclature confusion
Does anyone know what is the standard nomenclature used when talking about motor direction?
I see in some motor manuals the following are generally used:

Forward, Reverse direction
Clockwise, Counter-Clockwise direction
Deploy, Stow direction

Which is the most commonly used?
Also with these directions, it also depends on where the user is seeing the motor from.
What I mean by this is, for example Lets say a person is standing in front of the Motor and sees it moving in the clockwise direction, now another person is also seeing the same motor from the back, for this person the motor is moving in the counter-clockwise direction!!
This becomes confusing if the direction needs to be communicated to someone who isnt actually seeing the motor moving.
Any suggestions on how to clear this confusion? How is direction generally communicated in the industry?

I think the only one of those three that is 'standard' is clockwise / counter-clockwise.
The other two (forward, reverse; stow, deploy) would depend entirely on how the motor is mechanically connected to the rest of the system.  These would describe the movement of the system, not just the motor.
(And, yes, a motor with two shaft ends would have some confusion, which would be resolved on its nameplate or by some other means.)

Do you have an example of a name plate which can solve this confusion
